# magento 2 not reindexing two indexers - Catalog Product Rule and Product Categories

Tags: magento2, cron, indexer

i try to Reindexing Using this command :`bin/magento indexer:reindex`

It says it's updated all the **indexers** but when i return to **index management** in the admin these two indexers **(Catalog Product Rule and Product Categories)**

I have to do these manually by resetting them.

Ideally i want them to **reindex** at the same time as the others using a cron job.

Can anyone help me in getting this fixed?

here is a screenshot of my index management

[image]

Comment: Can you share any screenshots?

Comment: What status showing up for both indexer? It was showing processing or reindex required

Comment: @RajMohanR I have updated my post with a screenshot. as you can see the times are different. for product categories and catalog product rule and ideally want them to reindex at the same time as the others, which is not happening with my cron job. The cron job looks like this- 0 */4 * * * php-cli -f /home/xxxx/public_html/bin/magento indexer:reindex | grep -v "Ran Indexer by schedule" >> /home/xxxx/public_html/var/log/magento.indexer.log

Comment: @KamleshSolanki it was showing as ready but the updated time was wrong. was showing as november 8 2018 before i reset them both manually.

Comment: @dan You have set the reindex to happen upon save, so if you want to happen through cron change it to Update on Schedule. So if any lock occurs the we have to manually reset for the indexing to occur normally

Comment: @RajMohanR are you saying to set all of them to update on schedule or just Catalog Product Rule and Product Categories

Comment: @dan Update on save is set to update whenever entity change is saved whereas Update on schedule is set to update on cron jobs. So you can set accordingly. Please find this link which will be helpful for you https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/index-management.html.